# Custom training loop / loss function in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to define a multi-layer perceptron where the loss function is the L2 distance between the input of the network and a transformation of the output of the network (some black-box function that roughly transforms the output of the network back into the input space so it can be compared), i.e. `loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(input - transform(output)), 1)`.

The problem is that I need the output to be evaluated in order to transform it, but at the time of model definition, `output` is just a Tensor.

Is it possible to do this kind of custom training loop in TensorFlow?

Comment: you mean autoencoder?

Comment: Not quite, I think -- the transform here is some black-box function, not another network definition.